# Create multiple PDF files from one large PDF file based on page

Tags: powershell, pdf, split, pdftk

I have a large PDF file containing employee information. One page per employee, 500+ pages. I need to create a single PDF file per employee by splitting out this large file into smaller ones. I researched similiar questions regarding that subject here and found  a answer that may help but I have run into a glitch of sorts.

While the code executes without errors and says it is processing the files, even giving the file name, it outputs nothing at all. by output I mean no files are created

I am using PDFtk to accomplish this on Powershell. Hopefully someone can point out why I am not getting any output.

this is my code

```
$pdfPath = 'C:\pdffiles\'
$pdfFile = Join-Path $pdfPath "empdf.pdf"
$OutDir = "C:\TestOutput\"
$SetsOfPages = 2
$NumberOfPages = 546
for ($Page=1;$Page -le $NumberOfPages;$Page+=$SetsOfPages){
  $File = Get-Item $pdfFile
  $Range = "{0}-{1}" -f $page,[math]::min($Page+$SetsOfPages-1,$NumberOfPages)
  $OutFile = Join-Path $OutDir ($File.BaseName+"_$Range.pdf")
  "processing: {0}" -f $OutFile
  pdftk $pdfFile cat $Range Burst output $OutFile
}
```

I have ensured that the pdftk executable file is in the proper location. The code runs without any displayed errors.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious: Are you looking in `C:\TestOutput` for the output files? What exit code - as reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) - do the `pdftk` calls report?

Comment: FYI, with [QPDF](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), you can solve your problem with a simple, single line: `qpdf --split-pages empdf.pdf emp%d.pdf`.

Comment: mklement0 - LastExitCode is -1073741515 and the output directory is C:\TestOutput\

Comment: K J - the pdftk.exe file is located in the main powershell directory (C:\Windows\system32\Windowspowershell\v1.0\)  and it does not error out on execution so I am fairly sure that powershell knows where PDFTK.EXE is located.

Comment: @RobinOlsen, the error message means "The specified module could not be found" - https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_NT/0xC0000135

Comment: mklement0
Frustrating, the file pdftk.exe is definitely in a directory that that is included in the return values of $env:PSModulePath so now i am really confused as to why  I get 0 files outputed at all even though it does process them. Thank you for your help and comments

Comment: My pleasure, @RobinOlsen. It is actually `$env:PATH` that matters here, but, yes, _locating_ the executable isn't the problem here. Rather, it seem like its installation is incomplete or got corrupted ("module" in the context of the cited error does _not_ refer to PowerShell modules). I'm not familiar with `pdftk.exe`, but you can try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My pleasure, @RobinOlsen. It is actually `$env:PATH` that matters here, but, yes, locating the executable isn't the problem here. Rather, it seem like `pdftk.exe`'s installation is incomplete or got corrupted ("module" in the context of the cited error ([`-1073741515`](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_NT/0xC0000135), "The specified module could not be found.") does *not* refer to *PowerShell* modules).
I'm not familiar with pdftk.exe, but you can try reinstalling it."

–mklement0

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, but did you actually solve the problem, e.g, by reinstalling?

Comment: yes, that worked for me, I did not even install properly to begin with, just moved an exe file into the powershell path directory... I was originally getting an error that said the module was not found displayed, when I moved the file over to the powershell directory the error went away but it still did not create the files. I had to install the module. I am learning basic Powershell fairly quickly but third party modules I will have to learn how to deal with.